# How to use session in EL?

Tags: el

I have a class WebUtil and below method is inside it.

```
public static String  getOtp(HttpSession session){
    String val = getAttribute(session, AppAttr.OTP_MSG);
    if(val != null){
        session.removeAttribute(AppAttr.OTP_MSG.key);
    }
    return val;
}
```

I have mapped this method in a .tld file and want to use it in my jsp. Below 'util' is the prefix for the tld.

```
${util:getOtp(session)}
```

But the value of 'session' is null in the java method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use pageContext .. ${util:getOtp(pageContext.session)}

Comment: Thanks @MadhuBose, you saved my day :)